# How to import data from google spreadsheet in Highmaps map bubble

Tags: google-sheets, highcharts

I built a map bubble with Highmaps that works fine as long as it gets the data from this js file:

```
<script src="https://medien.lb.madsack.de/rnd/jchrist/coronaweltkarte.js"></script>
```

see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/4d3ox2vk/2/)

In the next step I want to import data from this google spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vkOXfueP5dsAdaRH433kP4SY1KJCxN6W7hPwj79zd_g/edit#gid=480378207

For that I added this code:

```
  data: {
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1vkOXfueP5dsAdaRH433kP4SY1KJCxN6W7hPwj79zd_g'
  },
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/t3a0huy8/1/)

Unfortunately it does not work. What else do I have to do?

Comment: I'd try to generate a JSON file from your datasheet, I found this tutorial (https://medium.com/@scottcents/how-to-convert-google-sheets-to-json-in-just-3-steps-228fe2c24e6).

After that you need to parse your JSON file.

Comment: Thank you, Bernardo. I tried to import data via JSON. At least the map is displayed, but the bubbles are still missing. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/fpgeawzh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `seriesMapping` property to correctly create bubble series from your data. Also, add the map series, for example in `complete` callback function.

```
data: {
  googleSpreadsheetKey: '1vkOXfueP5dsAdaRH433kP4SY1KJCxN6W7hPwj79zd_g',
  seriesMapping: [{
    z: 0,
    land: 4,
    lat: 5,
    lon: 6,
    infder: 3,
    totins: 1,
    genins: 2
  }],
  complete: function(options) {
    options.series[0].name = 'Infizierte';
    options.series.push({ // Add map series
      name: 'Länder'
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v3m59kyw/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/data.seriesMapping

Comment: Thank you, @ppotaczek The data import works fine now. But there appeared another problem. When I zoom initially the bubbles are at the correct place but the map behind them is not. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/ztb8dyu9/1/)

Comment: The zooming problem described above is solved over night without doing something. But  zooming in another way still makes problems: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/ztb8dyu9/6/)

Comment: The first version looks fine on desktop, but still makes problems on mobile devices: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/ztb8dyu9/1/)

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, I have tested your example and everything seems to be fine. Could you describe the problem more precisely?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, when the map is loaded for the first time the bubbles and the map do not fit together: https://johanneschrist.de/grafiken/weltkarte1.png For example the bubble for the USA is in the middle of the Atlantic. When I move the map by drag and drop or when I zoom in the map moves the the right place: https://johanneschrist.de/grafiken/weltkarte2.png

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, It looks that your data has changed. Could you reproduce the problem once again?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, when I open the map on desktop [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/ztb8dyu9/8/), the bubbles and the map are displayed correctly. But on mobile devices they do not fit together: [Screenshot](https://johanneschrist.de/grafiken/weltkarte3.png). When I once use the zoom they are again at the correct place.

Comment: @Johannes Christ, You need to call the `mapZoom` method after your data is loaded. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/740ugew8/1/